# Get ClassNotFoundException after change applicationId in app/build.gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After I changed applicationId in app/build.gradle , i got a ClassNotFoundException means can not find my Application class, I didn't change anything except applicationId.And before this, everything works fine.

Comment: You need the Application ID in your gradle file for Android Studio to differentiate between an application and a library. If you remove the AppID then Android Studio will consider it as a module/library

Comment: include your full stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0):

applicationId "com.example.developer.filter"-this is same for your all classes. Ensure that you have change the same folder name in your classes

Answer (score -1):

Please check your manifest.xml file